# Iframe приложение для Вконтакте

Tags: vkontakte-api, iframe

Доброй ночи, есть браузерная онлайн игра <a href="http://www.travianX5.ru">http://www.travianX5.ru</a>. Каким образом можно сделать из этой игры iframe приложения, чтобы выложить его Вконтакте и Facebook? Это вообще возможно? Что для этого потребуется? Что можно почитать? С какими проблемами придется столкнуться?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблем быть не должно, сайт просто открывается в iframe, соответственно в ВК и FB. При регистрации приложения выбираете пункт iframe приложение. В ВК необходимо будет дождаться модерации, прежде чем приложение будет доступно всем.